# mupdf - make could not find find header file

Tags: android, android-ndk, mupdf

I am trying to build a `mupdf-Lib` for my Android App. I have done every step of this [documentation](http://mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android)

By using `ndk-build` the console tells me that the thirdparty-lib `openjpeg.h` could not be found.

```
CC build/debug/fitz/load-jpx.o
source/fitz/load-jpx.c:11:22: schwerwiegender Fehler: openjpeg.h: No such file or directory
#include <openjpeg.h>
```

The lib is in the Thirdparty folder in newest version. I also tried it with different versions of `mupdf` and openjpeg. Also tried it on native ubuntu and cygwin.
Has anyone run into an similar problem?

I would be pleased to hear from you :-)

Comment: did u tried with the older version?

Comment: Hi, I also tried older versions of mupdf

Comment: What do you mean by 'The lib is in the Thirdparty folder in newest version.'? Did you manually do this? 'git submodule update --init' should have put the *correct* version of openjpg into the third party folder.

Comment: I added it with the http protocol out of the git repo because the git protocol isnt allowed in my network.

Comment: @Will Torres, which version did you use?

Comment: @Darthmail I think this is the problem. Can you delete everything, go back to the start, and before running the git submodules update --init change the urls in .gitmodules in the root of your newly cloned tree to use http: instead of git:

Comment: @JosephH 37 thank you very much that solved the error with openjpeg :-)  but now I get the same error with X11/extensions/XShm.h  :-(

Comment: @Darthmail I suggesting capturing the full contents of the console window you've done this in (which should include all the commands you've run starting with the git clone, any files you've changed, and the full text of the latest error) and adding it into your question.

Comment: @JosephH I deleted the "HAVE_X11" condition of the Makefile and now everything works as expected :-)

Comment: @Darthmail Awesome, well done. I wonder if there's a bug in the makefiles - what platform are you building on? (OS X, Linux or Windows?)